# Does Applescript have an "exit" or "die" command similar to PHP?

Tags: macos, error-handling, applescript

How can I throw an error and exit in Applescript? I'd like to have something like PHP's `die` or `exit` command so that the "completed" dialog does not fire.

```
function1()
display dialog "completed"

on function1()
    function2()
end function1

on function2()
    exit //what do i use here?
end function2
```

Here is what I've tried with the answer that was posted below:

```
function1()
display dialog "completed"

on function1()
    function2()
end function1

on function2()

    try
        display dialog "Do you want to catch an error?" buttons {"Continue without error", "Cause an error"} default button 2
        if button returned of result is "Cause an error" then
            error "I'm causing an error and thus it is caught in 'on error'"
        end if
        display dialog "completed without error"
    on error theError
        return theError -- this ends the applescript when an error occurs
    end try


end function2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
-- errors are only handled inside of a "try" block of code
try
    display dialog "Do you want to catch an error?" buttons {"Continue without error", "Cause an error"} default button 2
    if button returned of result is "Cause an error" then
        error "I'm causing an error and thus it is caught in 'on error'"
    end if
    display dialog "completed without error"
on error theError
    return theError -- this ends the applescript when an error occurs
end try
```

**EDIT**: Based on your comment... just return values from your functions. Check that returned value in your main code where you call the functions and the return value will tell you if you should "quit" the application or not. As such here's one way to solve your example problem...

```
set returnValue to function1()

-- we check the return value from the handler
if returnValue is not true then return -- this "quits" the script

display dialog "completed"

on function1()
    set returnValue to function2()
    return returnValue
end function1

-- note that when there is no error the the script returns true.
-- so we can check for that and actt appropriately in the main script
on function2()
    try
        display dialog "Do you want to catch an error?" buttons {"Continue without error", "Cause an error"} default button 2
        if button returned of result is "Cause an error" then
            error "I'm causing an error and thus it is caught in 'on error'"
        end if
        display dialog "completed without error"
        return true
    on error theError
        return theError -- this ends the applescript when an error occurs
    end try
end function2
```

Comment: Basically what you're doing is using "return" when you're not inside a function. What I want to know is if there is a way to stop the script while inside the funciton. I've updated my example to use some of your code - it does not work in that type of scenario. Thoughts?

Comment: I added an "EDIT" section in my answer to answer your question.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I guess that means there is no command you can use to stop the script immediately in the middle of a function.

Comment: You can always create your own errors. An error number -128 is "user cancelled", which will end the script - is that what you are wanting to do?